# Dropped database phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I was deleting some databases from the phpMyAdmin and I dropped the database `phpmyadmin`. Now that's causing all kinds of problems.

Do I have to reinstall phpMyAdmin or can I get back/download only the database somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sql file in phpmyadmin to (re-)create that db: /phpmyadmin/examples/create_tables.sql

Comment: That created the database but I'm still getting phpMyAdmin errors (for example: trying to view a database's tables). Guess I better just try to reinstall, hope I don't loose anything and that it goes all back to normal.